# javascript prototypes and memory

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I'm attending a boot camp and today in class the following statement was made:

"Generally speaking, when using a constructor, if you are going to want every object to have access to a function, put that function in the prototype, as opposed to within the original constructor. This will save memory because instead of creating a new function upon every invocation of the object, every object will simply refer to the prototype when using that function."

Can anyone please explain/validate?

Comment: the statement is valid

Comment: This isn't a suitable question here, so you'll probably get closed. But the reason is also for maintenance. There needs to be many such methods or instances before the extra memory use is significant.

Comment: Why isn't it a suitable question?

Comment: Simplified down, _getting a value from an Object_ works a bit like this: Let `o` be the object you're trying to access a property `p` from. 1. If `o` does not have **own** property `p`, let `o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);` and go back to 1. otherwise 2. if `o` is _undefined_ return _undefined_. 3. return the value of own property `p` of `o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Generally speaking, when using a constructor, if you are going to
>   want every object to have access to a function, put that function in
>   the prototype, as opposed to within the original constructor. This
>   will save memory because instead of creating a new function upon every
>   invocation of the object, every object will simply refer to the
>   prototype when using that function."

That statement is true.

One significant characteristic of the `prototype` is that it is a single object that is shared among all instances of that type of object.

So, any methods put on the prototype are shared among all instances of that type of object.  This "sharing" of the single prototype object is a memory efficient way for all objects to have access to a common set of methods/properties.

If you initialize the methods in the constructor like this:

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.print = function() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Then, each time the constructor is called (each new instance of the object) creates a new function object and assigns a new own property and this does use a bit more memory.

---

Now, it is a separate question whether this use of more memory is actually relevant or not.  It doesn't use a lot more memory unless you have a lot of those types of objects.

There are some (Douglas Crockford, for one) that are advocating a specific method of coding object definitions that does not use the prototype and he argues that the extra use of memory is inconsequential vs. the benefits of his method.  Since the new "class" syntax in ES6 is still using the prototype (under the covers), it appears that his view has not been accepted by those directing the future of the language.

If you want "private" member variables that only some methods of the instance can access and cannot be accessed from the outside world, then you will probably want to declare those member variables as local variables in the constructor and assign any methods that you want to be able to access those "private" member variables inside the constructor (you can't put them on the prototype).  You can see Crockford's writeup on how to make "private" instance variables in [his writeup here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).  This can be very useful in some circumstances where privacy (or sometimes security) of the variable is important.

For some of Crockford's view on the prototype, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo36MrBfTk4) (go to the 31:30 point in the video and then the 36:00 point after that).

Comment: "*It appears that this view has not been accepted by those directing the future of the language*" - well, there are other benefits of the prototype approach as well, and both views/patterns are accepted. It depends on what you need/like, and both are viable. ES6 has syntactically simplified both ways.

Comment: @Bergi - My point was that if those directing the future of the language thought that it was always or even usually better to NOT put methods on the prototype, they would not have made it so that the definition of an object using the `class` keyword put those methods on the prototype.  Clearly, they intend to continue supporting the prototype for a long time and are not moving the language away from it in any way.  How has ES6 simplified a different way of declaring objects?

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript will (and can) certainly not move away from having a prototype-base object model, but it will stay a multi-paradigm language that supports many ways of doing a thing. Crockfords pattern has always been syntactically simple, one could argue that destructuring and property shorthands make it even easier to use.